# Ajax populate 2 other selects

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm having problems with my Ajax multiselect. I posted my 3 files im using.

If i remove the if(!empty($_POST["customerID"])), the WHERE and the elseif i get the files to work so the SQL query should be correct.

My system is using materialize.css with loads of other Jquery elements so it should be working.

My index.php file with the select:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli(servername, username, password, dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY customerName ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
<select id="customer">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <?php
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option name="customerID" value="'.$row['customerID'].'">'.$row['customerName'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Country not available</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>

<select id="project">
    <option value="">Select country first</option>
</select>

<select id="subproject">
    <option value="">Select state first</option>
</select>
```

My Jquery to handle my data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#customer').on('change',function(){
    var customerID = $(this).val();
    if(customerID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'loadProjects.php',
            data:'customerID='+customerID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#project').html(html);
                $('#subproject').html('<option value="">Select project 

first</option>');
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('#project').html('<option value="">Select customer first</option>');
            $('#subproject').html('<option value="">Select project first</option>');
        }
});

$('#project').on('change',function(){
    var projectID = $(this).val();
    if(projectID){
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'loadProjects.php',
        data:'projectID='+projectID,
        success:function(html){
            $('#subproject').html(html);
        }
    });
    }else{
        $('#subproject').html('<option value="">Select project first</option>');
    }
});
});
```

My loadProjects.php handling the MySQL fetching

```
<?php include("./includes/db.php"); ?>

<?php
$conn = new mysqli(servername, username, password, dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(!empty($_POST["customerID"])){
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE customerID = ".$_POST['customerID']."");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select project</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['projectID'].'">'.$row['projectName'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Project not available</option>';
    }
elseif(!empty($_POST["projectID"])){
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM subproject WHERE projectID = ".$_POST['projectID']."");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select subproject</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['subprojectID'].'">'.$row['subProjectName'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Subproject not available</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Try instead `empty()` use `isset()`

Comment: @J.Litvak thank you but it didnt work with that either. :/

Comment: You cannot have `if-else-elseif` It should be `if-elseif-else`

Comment: @MilanChheda it's correct. the `elseif` is of the parent if

Comment: @Gardezi `elseif(!empty($_POST["projectID"])){` is out of sync. this should come after the parent `if`

Comment: @MilanChheda it is coming after the parent `if` which is `if(!empty($_POST["customerID"])){`

I think the problem is he is not closing the bracket of the parent `if`

Comment: I think i missed a } according to my editor but that didnt solve the issue either.

Comment: Your missing your bracket add one closing curly bracket } before the elseif(!empty($_POST['projectID'])) and change your if statment to if(isset($_POST['customerID']) && !empty($_POST['customerID']))

Comment: @SimonGottberg did you try using `isset`

Comment: I have tried @Dee option with if(isset($_POST['customerID']) && !empty($_POST['customerID'])) but it still dosnt work. :/

Is the problem with my JS not passing the right values?

Comment: @SimonGottberg error log the values coming from the server.

Comment: @Gardezi Do you mean my Apache error logs? I get no errors from there.

Comment: @SimonGottberg I mean to say log the data that is coming from the server

Comment: @Gardezi im getting a POST value using the dev tool in FireFox + im getting a response with the right project options now. The only thing missing is that the projects dosnt get populated with the select options. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Now i can alert the html with the response but i still dont get the values to my select.

Comment: Hello again! I solved the issue by disabling materalize.css. I found out that the select had to be initialized everytime the elements change. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @SimonGottberg Then post the solution as an answer and accept it.